# incorrect decimal null value warning in select statement

Tags: mysql, sqlexception

So I get this exception when running a select statement on a view.

WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper 233 - Incorrect decimal value: 'null' for column  at row 1

I know this error/warning can happen when inserting or updating values. But will it happen when you're trying to read from a row that has null for decimal column?

Comment: read no, and if you try and filter by NULL you can't use = sign (`where field = null`) would fail `coalesce(field,0)` would always ensure you get a 0  returned and 0 could be compared with an equality check.  so where `coalesce(Field,0) =` 0 would work but 0 is not null.

Comment: Please post your java code and query.

Comment: That's the issue. I have an API that only does read operations, but I see this error in the logs everytime the API is called. I don't know which query is causing this warning

Comment: Update: Looks like mysql throws this error even for 'select' queries. Verified this via dbvisualizer. That answers my question. Thank you